# ll Centos Xinetd

Tags: linux, xinetd

I have CentOS servers 5.5 and I see that the Xinetd is not install on any of them. Do you think it will be wise to install xinetd or not? These are production systems.

Answer (score 2):

Xinetd is a service that manage internet connection type. It's a version more securised than inetd.

Xinetd is often used for monitoring (nagios, cacti, zabix, etc...)

Like ewwhite said, the install of xinted depend of what you do with your server. I did installed it on my servers, but on those where i don't need it 24/24, 7/7 I just stop it, and on the other (that are critical and need to be monitored), the service run 24/24 7/7!

hope that'll help you.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on if you need to run any xinetd services, like telnet.

Comment: You should **never** *need* to run telnet.

Comment: I'll bite... Some warehousing and industrial ERP applications that use hardware terminals or serial terminal servers leverage telnet. I also see a lot of legacy systems (converted from SCO) that require telnet and don't support SSH.

Comment: Nonsense - the only relevance telnet has over ssh is on **very high** security **legacy** systems where an ssh server cannot be deployed (and IME, these are generally considered an oxymoron by the people who run such systems - i.e. the military). There are legacy systems out there which are hard-coded to run on old terminal hardware (up until recently I looked after a system which would only talk to Data General 400 terminal - last manufactured about 30 years ago) but it's trivial to connect a telnet emulator to an SSH connection on the client.